# question related to equicontinuous set

Tags: piecewise-continuity, equicontinuity

I have come across one problem. I have a set,  $T=\{f | f:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ where each $f$ is a piecewise continuous function on $[a, b]$. Can we talk about equicontinuity of the ser $T?$

Comment: Just for simplicity consider $[a,b]=[0,1].$ Is $\{f_n:x\in[0,1]\to nx\in\mathbb{R}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a subset of $T?$ Is it equicontinuous?

Comment: This is not an equicontinuous set. But i have one example in which i have shown that $ |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<K|x_1-x_2| $ for all  $ f\in T$ where K is a constant. Then can we conclude  $ T$ is equicontinuous?

Comment: In such a case the set is equicontinuous.

Comment: It means for a set to be an equicontinuous set, each element of the set not necessarily to be continuous function. Can we conclude this?

Comment: No. Every function in the set must be continuous. And, moreover, given $x_0$ then $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta, f\in T\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon.$ That is, $\delta$ is the same for each element of $T.$

Comment: Further if we know that T is subset of the nonempty, closed, bounded, convex set, then can we apply Arzela -Ascoli theorem to conclude that $closure (T)$ is compact set?

Comment: Yes, in my example  $ \delta $ is independent of elements of  $ T$ hence set  $ T$ should be equicontinuous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47293/discussion-between-vijayakumar-muni-and-mfl).

Comment: Family T is relatively compact if and only if T is equibounded and equicontinuous. This is Arzela Ascoli theorem

Answer (score 1):

(1).Yes. This comes up in the proofs of existence of solutions of certain integral or differential equations. Let $F$ be a family of continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R.$ For $x\in [a,b]$ we say that $F$ is equicontinuous at $x$ iff $$\forall r>0 \;\exists s>0 \;
\forall f\in F \;(y\in [a,b]\land |y-x|<s\implies |f(y)-f(x)|<r).$$
(2).A continuous $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous. That is $$\forall r>0\;\exists s>0\; ((x,y\in [a,b]\land |x-y|<s)\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<r).$$

If the $F,$ above, is equicontinuous at every $x\in [a,b]$ then we also have $$\forall r>0\; \exists s>0\; \forall f\in F \;((x,y\in [a,b]\land |x-y|<s)\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<r).$$ To prove this, by contradiction, suppose not. Then take $r_0>0$ such that for each $n\in \mathbb N$ we have some $f_n\in F$ and $x_n,y_n \in [a,b]$ with $$(0<|x_n-y_n|<1/n)\; \land \;(|f_n(x_n)-f_n(y_n)|\geq r_0).$$ Now let $(x_{n_j})_j$ be a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)_n,$ converging to $x.$ Since $|x_{n_j}-y_{n_j}|<1/n_j,$ the sequence $(y_{n_j})_j$ also converges to $x.$

Now $F$ is equicontinuous at $x,$ so take $s>0$ such that $$\forall f\in F ((y\in [a,b]\land |y-x|<s)\implies |f(y)-f(x)|<r_0/2.$$  But there exists $j$ such that $\{x_{n_j},y_{n_j}\}\subset (x-s,x+s)$. (In fact this holds for all but finitely many values of $j$.) For such $j$ we have  $$r_0\leq |f_{n_j}(x_{n_j})-f_{n_j}(y_{n_j})|\leq |f_{n_j}(x_{n_j})-f_{n_j}(x)|+ |f_{n_j}(x)-f_{n_j}(y_{n_j})|<r_0/2+r_0/2=r_0,$$ implying $r_0<r_0.$

Answer (score 0):

No.

If $F$ is a family of  equicontinuous functions, then each $f \in F$ is  continuous. Your Family $T$ contains many functions, which ar not continuous.

Comment: Dear fred, can you answer to above comments?